# 6 ST7735 screens not working at same time with Pico

Tags: raspberrypi-pico

Hello i have a question for you. I have 6 St7735s screen 0.96 ınch. I connect them to my Raspberry pi pico. I want to show them some text but they are showing at the same time. First screen start working and shows "Screen 1 Test" and then its close. After that second screen start working and show "Screen 2 Test" and its close again and it goes to last screen and it show "Screen 6 test" and not closing. But the rest of it stay close. I use same connection for GND - VCC - SCL - SDA - RES - DC pins. Only Cs pin is diffrent. Any advice for me?

The code that i used :

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define TFT_CS1 2
#define TFT_CS2 3
#define TFT_CS3 4
#define TFT_CS4 5
#define TFT_CS5 14
#define TFT_CS6 15
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_RST 7

Adafruit_ST7735 tfts[] = {
  Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS1, TFT_DC, TFT_RST),
  Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS2, TFT_DC, TFT_RST),
  Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS3, TFT_DC, TFT_RST),
  Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS4, TFT_DC, TFT_RST),
  Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS5, TFT_DC, TFT_RST),
  Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS6, TFT_DC, TFT_RST)
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    tfts[i].initR(INITR_MINI160x80);
    tfts[i].setRotation(3);
    tfts[i].fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);
    tfts[i].setTextColor(ST7735_WHITE);
    tfts[i].setTextSize(2);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    tfts[i].setCursor(0, 0);
    tfts[i].println("Screen " + String(i+1) + " test");
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you iterate through the screens in a descending order?

Comment: I didnt understand but if i lower delay time it still working same

Comment: go through the screens in the 6, 5, 4 order

Comment: You might want to have separate reset pin for each, it probably resets all displays and initialize one of them.

Comment: Or you can try if it's possible to configure only first object with TFT_RST and the rest with -1 instead. But it might be checked somewhere.